# Is it Possible to find whether Twitter's Remember me button is clicked?

Tags: iphone, twitter

Is it possible for us to find whether twitter **Remember Me** button is clicked or not from our iphone application??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the "remember me" button in the Twitter application, then **no**, you can't. The only way for applications to communicate is through URL schemes (or if they share a keychain). They can't read each other's preference files.